# DataGrid header columns are not in bold

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In all the examples I see on the official [MUI](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/layout/) site, the header columns appear styled in bold - this is how I would expect it too.

However, when I am integrating `DataGrid` in my project, the columns appear in normal text, not in bold. This is super unintuitive.

[image]

Here the react component for the above data grid:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

export default function FixedSizeGrid() {
    const columns = [
        {
            field: 'symbol', headerName: 'Symbol', flex: 0.5,
        },
        {
            field: 'company', headerName: 'Company', flex: 2,
        },
    ];

    const rows = [
        { id: 1, symbol: 'PP', company: 'Private Pen' },
        { id: 1, symbol: 'AR', company: 'Antero Resources' },
    ];

    return (
        <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
            <div style={{ height: 350, width: '100%' }}>
                <DataGrid
                    rows={rows}
                    columns={columns}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I then tried to use custom header classes for the individual columns:

```js
const columns = [
        {
            ..., headerClassName: 'super-app-theme--header'
        },
        {
            ..., headerClassName: 'super-app-theme--header'
        },
    ];

// App.css
.super-app-theme--header {
  background-color: #red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

This changes the background header color to red, yet the font is still not bold :(.

Any ideas what could I be missing?

Comment: You have a problem somewhere in another part of the application, the content of your FixedSizeGrid function in the sandbox it works as expected.